# Compiler Error while trying to call overloaded contstructors in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance

Could someone explain to me why I get a compiler error when I try to call a base class' constructor from an inherited object?  I've included a brief example of what I'm referring to.

```
Public Class Person
    Public name As String

    Public Sub New()
        name = "John Doe"
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(Name As String)
        name = Name
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class NamedPerson
    Inherits Person

    Public Sub New(FirstName As String, LastName As String)
        name = FirstName & " " & LastName
    End Sub

    'adding this makes it work
    Public Sub New(Name As String)
       MyBase.New(Name)
    End Sub

End Class

'Valid
Dim guy1 As Person = New Person()

'Valid 
Dim guy2 As Person = New Person("John Smith")

'Valid
Dim guy3 As NamedPerson = New NamedPerson("John", "Smith")

'Compiler Error
Dim guy4 As NamedPerson = New NamedPerson("John Smith")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Child classes do not inherit constructors from their base types. A child class is responsible for defining it's own constructors. Additionally it must ensure that each constructor it defines either implicitly or explicitly calls into a base class constructor or chains to another constructor in the same type.

**[For more info See: Instance Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711964%28VS.71%29.aspx)**

From your sample classes,

```
Public Class NamedPerson
    Inherits Person

    Public Sub New(Name As String)
        MyBase.New(Name)
    End Sub

    Public sub New(FirstName As String, LastName As String)
        name = FirstName & " " & LastName
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So essentially if I want the same method signature on the child class, I have to expose it and call the base class.